# Why can't I test on my iPhone after upgrading it to iOS 6?

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios-simulator, ios6, simulator

I'm running Xcode 4.2 on Snow Leopard. I have upgraded my iPhone 4S to iOS 6, and now it's saying:

> No provisioning iOS devices are available with a compatible iOS version...

whenever I try to perform tests on said device.

Am I going to need to completely upgrade my system, Xcode, etc. just because I upgraded iOS 6?
IS there any way I could just install the iOS 6 version on my Xcode 4.2?  I've been searching around, but sadly have had no real luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to match the iOS version with the SDK version, while the target iOS version can be different. So you need iOS SDK 6, that might require you to install Xcode 4.4 or 4.5 but you can still create projects targeting iOS 5. This way the signing and certificates will work.

Comment: So before I can install Xcode 4.4, I need to upgrade to Lion?  All because I went to ios 6?

Comment: You will need 4.5 actually, as only 4.5 includes the iOS 6 SDK. And yes, that means you'll need to upgrade to Lion as well. Or Mountain Lion, of course.

Comment: It should not be a problem to upgrade and you should not lose any data, one of my older systems is an Early 2008 MacBook Pro and is running Mountain Lion with Xcode 4.5 nearly as good as my Mid 2011 model

Comment: Of course my mini mac only has 1gb of ram and Lion requires 2gb.  so now I need to upgrade the ram, then to lion, then to xcode 4.5.  jeez, I would have stayed with ios 5 if I knew that!